# Django doesn't render template

Tags: python, django

I type this code in my `index.html`:

```
   <h1>Im an index page.</h1>

    {% for post in posts %}
       <div>
            <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
           <p>{{ posts.summary }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

but when I execute it I, my page looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You need a view to render the template, and a URL pattern for the view. You haven't included either of these in your question.

Comment: It looks like your web server is delivering the page directly, without being processed by Django.  Did you set up your web server to work with Django?

Comment: More information would be good. The code of the view used to build that page would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include

url(r'^your_appname',include('your_appname.urls')),
```

in app urls.py:

```
from  .views import *
url=(r'^$',views.index,name='index')
```

in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from .models import *

def inedx(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'html_page_location/index.html',{'posts':posts})
```

If you do this data will be rendered into your html templates.